# Magento 2.2.x debug in NetBeans IDE 8.1 via chrome or mozilla

Tags: magento2, debug, xdebug

In order to debug `PHP scripts` in `NetBeans IDE 8.1` via Chrome or Mozilla.

What i need to `install` for Browser and which code i should put in my **Magento** project and `php.ini` file?

What changes i need to made in `php.ini` file related to `[XDebug]` ?

My system configuration is

```
7.0.27-1+ ubuntu14.04.1 + deb.sury.org+1

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
```

If anyone is aware about the whole process then please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Chrome to successfully listen, you need to install the "Xdebug helper" this extension for Chrome.
Next, do everything like this guy, and you should work

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869189/netbeans-and-xdebug-in-linux

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Evgeniy Kapelko, i'll look in to that.